# const propagation to std::array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constants, type-deduction

Why is `std::array`'s data type being instantiated differently here

```
using T = const int *;
std::array<T, 4> x = { &a, &b, &c, &d }; // name: class std::array<int const *,4>
x[0] = &c; // OK    : non-constant pointer
*x[0] = c; // Error : constant data
```

compared to here?

```
using T = int *;
std::array<const T, 4> x = { &a, &b, &c, &d }; // name: class std::array<int * const,4>
x[0] = &c; // Error : constant pointer
*x[0] = c; // OK    : non-constant data
```

This second case is equivalent to `const std::array<T, 4>` (constant pointers to non-constant data). 
If we use `const int *` directly: `std::array<const int*, 4>` we get first case behavior.

So more precisely, why is `using T = int*; std::array<const T, 4>;` equivalent to `std::array<int*const, 4>` and not `std::array<const int*, 4>`?

Comment: The short answer is: because that's how C++ works. The type is a pointer to something. Applying the `const` modifier makes it a constant pointer to something. The End.

Comment: Just because I want to tattoo your home address on my chest, doesn't mean you aren't allowed to move.

Comment: one is a const pointer to mutable objects and one is a mutable pointer to const objects

Comment: Thanks all! The bit I was missing was that `const T` qualified `T` as constant, before `T` was deduced/substituted. I incorrectly thought `T` was substituted directly in place (like a macro) rather than treated as its own type, with its own qualifiers.

Comment: This is why I slightly prefer putting `const` after the type it qualifies. That way `T const` with `T = int *` becomes `int * const` as it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why is `using T = int*; std::array<const T, 4>;` equivalent to `std::array<int*const, 4>` and not `std::array<const int*, 4>`?

Because `const` is qualified on `T`, the pointer itself, it's not (and couldn't be) qualified on the pointee. So `const T` means `const` pointer, not pointer to `const`.

The rule is same, whether `T` is pointer or not.

```
using T = int;   // const T => int const
using T = int*;  // const T => int* const, not int const*
using T = int**; // const T => int** const, neither int* const*, nor int const**
```

Note the 3rd example, if `const` is qualified on the pointee, `const T` should be `int* const*`, or it should be qualified on the pointee of pointee, i.e. `int const**`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to be sure I've understood, am I correct in thinking: type deduction occurs after const qualification? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: @Judge No type deduction here, the type is specified explicitly.

Comment: Good point :) and thank you for the edit, it makes more lexicographical sense for it to be this way round now. Let me rephrase the question: does const qualification occur before type substitution? Is this also true for other modifiers, like `volatile`?

Comment: @Judge If I understand your question correctly, yes, const qualification occurs firstly, then the type is determined. And yes, this is true for `volatile` too.

Comment: That's cleared a lot of confusion up for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
using T = const int *; //T is a pointer to a CONSTANT integer.
std::array<T, 4> x = { &a, &b, &c, &d }; //array of PointerToConstantInteger, size=4
```

Change the elements of array `x`, but don't dereference and try changing value stored inside it.

```
using T = int *;  //T is a pointer to an integer.
std::array<const T, 4> x = { &a, &b, &c, &d }; //array of CONSTANT IntegerPointer, size=4
```

Can't change the elements of array `x`, but no problem in dereferencing and changing value stored inside it.